# Query is one character behind Value in my React.Js script

Tags: reactjs

```
const SearchBar = ({ onSearch }) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [userSearch, setUserSearch] = useState(null);
  const [suggestions, setSuggestions] = useState(new Set());
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (query.trim() !== "") {
      onSearch(query);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const userData = await fetchSearchData();
        setUserSearch(userData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching user data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    
    const value = event.target.value;
    setQuery(value);
    
    if (userSearch !== null) {
      const filteredSuggestions = Object.values(userSearch)
        .filter(user => user && user.name && user.last_name)
        .filter(user => {
          const lowercaseName = user.name.toLowerCase();
          const lowercaseLastName = user.last_name.toLowerCase();
          const lowercaseValue = value.toLowerCase();
          return (
            lowercaseName.includes(lowercaseValue) ||
            lowercaseLastName.includes(lowercaseValue)
          );
        });
    
      const uniqueSuggestions = new Set(filteredSuggestions.map(user => `${user.name} ${user.last_name}`));
    
      setSuggestions(uniqueSuggestions);
    } else {
      console.error("userSearch is null or invalid:", userSearch);
      setSuggestions(new Set());
    }
    
  };

  const handleClear = () => {
    setQuery("");
    setSuggestions(new Set());
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Backspace" && query === "") {
      handleClear();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="search-bar-container">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="search-form">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search..."
          value={query}
          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="search-input"
        />
        <button type="submit" className="search-icon-button">
          <SearchIcon className="search-icon" />
        </button>
        {suggestions.size < 10 && (
          <div className="suggestions-dropdown">
            {[...suggestions].map((suggestion, index) => (
              <div
                key={index}
                className="suggestion"
                onClick={() => setQuery(suggestion)}
              >
                {suggestion}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Below is a snip of where I am setting `query`. Here is an example, when I type B, `value` is set to B but `query` is set to nothing then when I key BB `value` is set to BB and `query` is so to B and so. For this reason when I hit backspace even when my searchbar is cleared out I still have to hit backspace one more time until the bar is closed.

This is where I am confused about
`const value = event.target.value;`
`setQuery(value);`

when I log `query` I am always one character behind `value`. I have tried many different ways but I just can't figure this one out. Also I have looked at other answers on the forum and don't seem to still figure it out. Your help is appreciated.